# Create interactive plot using radio buttons

Tags: python, radio-button, interactive

Plot an interactive plot in which a radio buttons widget (refer to the documentation below) allows users to select a cut type among All, Fair, Good, Ideal, Premium, and Very Good, and interactively displays the dataframe that contains the rows with the selected cut type. For example, if the user selects the Premium cut type, it displays the dataframe that contains the rows with the Premium cut. If the user selects All, it displays the entire dataframe with all rows. The default value for the widget is All. To display a dataframe dftmp, use display(dftmp). Do not use the print function.

I'm getting this error ('RadioButtons' object is not subscriptable), with the following code I wrote:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets, interactive, Layout

dftmp = widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['All', 'Fair', 'Good', 'Ideal', 'Premium', 'Very Good'],
    description='Cut Type:',
    disabled=False
)

def filter_dataframe(cut_type):
    if cut_type == 'All':
        dftmp = dfdi
    else:
        dftmp = dfdi[dfdi.cut == cut_type]

title = "Cut Type for {}".format(cut_type)
dftmp[["All", "Fair", "Good", "Ideal", "Premium", "Very Good"]].plot(kind="box", title=title, grid=True, figsize=(15,7))

i = interactive(view, cut_type=dftmp)
display(i)
```